# Git LFS won't ignore files

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Trying to push a project to Github, but I have a couple of compiled (.exe and .msi) files that are larger than the 50MB size limits.  I installed LFS from Github, tracked all .exe and .msi files, added a .getattributes, committed and tried to push the project again.  I still get the warning about those files.

Since they are compiled and not needed in the repo directly, I even tried to just delete them, commit again and push.  Same errors.  It's still finding them for some reason, even though they don't exist.

I'm at a loss and not sure how to clear them and push my project.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you removed the .exe and .msi files from all versions in the Git history?

Comment: honestly, not 100% sure how to do that.

Comment: You need to use the "git filter-branch" command to rewrite the history. I don't know if it's the case but maybe it's acceptable to initiate a new repository with just the last version. What do you thing?